# Getting the url of webpage on Timout (Python Slenium)

Tags: python, selenium, url, web-scraping, timeout

My question is how to get the URL of a webpage in selenium while a page timeout.
The website is not loading completely but I want to get the URL before the website has finished to load (which is never going to happen).
Does someone have a Idea how to get the URL?

```
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        profile = {"download.default_directory": "NUL", "download.prompt_for_download": False, }
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.header_overrides = {
            'Referer': 'referer_string',
        }
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
        driver.get(NEVERLOADINGLINK)
        a = driver.current_url
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use a try catch block. `Try` the code that may timeout, and then `catch` the resulting exception.

```
driver = ...
# Do stuff before going to the site
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
try:
    driver.get("NEVERLOADINGLINK")
    print("Page loaded")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed to load the page:", driver.current_url)
```